# All my buttons look like each other

Tags: css, button

I have two buttons at the centre of my page with this css design.

```
button{
outline: none;
text-align: center;
border-radius:15px 50px 30px;
}
.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}
.button:active{
background-color: #3e8e41;
box-shadow:0 5px #666;
transform:translateY(4px);
}  
#javaBtn{
color: #fff;
box-shadow:0 9px #999;
background-color:#2ECC71;
border: none;
padding: 15px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 12px;
}

#layoutBtn{
color: #fff;
box-shadow:0 9px #999;
background-color:#2ECC71;
border: none;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 15px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

My html:

```
 <div align="center">
    <img src="yalda.jpg" class= "mainPic">
</div>

<div align="center">
    <button  class="button" id="layoutBtn">Layouts</button>
    <button class="button" id="javaBtn">Java</button>
</div>

<div align="left">
    <img src="me.jpg" class= "myPic">
    <p><font color="white"> <i>some text</i></font></p>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    <a href="&" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin" ></a>
    <button class="googleBtn">some text</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to create another button with a different css design but my third button inherits the css design from the first two and looks kinda like them. What can I do about it?

Comment: Post HTML code!

Comment: you don't have a CSS rule for `.googleBtn` in your code, so the `button` rule applies to it

Comment: Write your style like this to overwrite the main button: `button.googleBtn{ color: red;}`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to declare a CSS rule for `.googleBtn` with different styles in the rule. Also I noticed that the two rules in your CSS, `#layoutBtn` and `#javaBtn`, styles are exactly the same. Instead, you can define one rule for both `#layoutBtn` and `#javaBtn` with that style of button and another for `.googleBtn`.

Answer (score 1):

The third button looks like your first two buttons because you did not create a style that is specific to it. Your first rule applies to all of the buttons on the page:

> ```
> button {
>     outline: none;
>     text-align: center;
>     border-radius:15px 50px 30px;
> }
> ```

Unlike your second two rules, here you wrote `button` and not `.button`. This means that it will select all elements of type `button`, not all elements that have `class="button"`.

Additionally, if you want your third button (I am assuming that this is the one with `class="googleBtn"`) to look very different, then you must create a style rule that selects it, like so:

```
.googleBtn {
    color: red;
    /* replace this with your style rules */
}
```

Side note: the HTML `align` attribute, and the `<font>` element have been deprecated for **years**. Please do not use this to format your page.